# Thumb Bundle for Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

Is there a bundle (symfony 2) for making thumbnails like sfThumb (symfony 1.4) plugin ?
And I want to integrate it with FOS User bundle.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle).

The bundle does non need to be integrated with FOSUB